# How to get the array elements within a range

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the array elements within a range but failed to do so. Explaining it below.

```
$date_array = array('2012-08-02','2012-08-09','2012-08-16','2012-08-23');
$start_date = '2012-08-01';
$end_date   = '2012-08-10';
```

I want to get the array elements from the $date_array within $start_date and $end_date.
i.e, output will be : 2012-08-02 and 2012-08-09.

**Edit:**

The array can be the following as well.

```
$date_array = array('2012-08-02','2012-08-10','2012-08-16','2012-08-23');
```

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? is this your homework?

Comment: What is generating the array?

Comment: Have a look at [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

Comment: @ gopi1410 and Wesley Murch: I tried to use array_search and array_filter at first. But did not understand the functionality of array_filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using [`array_filter`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_filter) and a callback that fulfills your needs:

```
$filter = function($start, $end) {
    return function($string) use ($start, $end) {
        return $string >= $start && $string <= $end;
    };
};

$result = array_filter($array, $filter('2012-08-01', '2012-08-10'));
```

Take care of the order of the parameters and as well that you have these exact formats because only those can the done with a simple string comparison.

---

For PHP 5.2 compatibility and also to solve this for iterators and not only arrays, here is a more general approach:

```
class Range
{
    private $from;
    private $to;
    public function __construct($from, $to) {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
        if ($from > $to) {
            $this->reverse();
        }
    }
    private function reverse() {
        list($this->from, $this->to) = array($this->to, $this->from);
    }
    public function in($value) {
        return $this->from <= $value && $value <= $this->to;
    }
}

class RangeFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $range;
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, Range $range) {
        $this->range = $range;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $value = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return $this->range->in($value);
    }
}

$range = new Range($start, $end);
$it = new ArrayIterator($array);
$filtered = new RangeFilter($it, $range);
$result = iterator_to_array($filtered);
```

Comment: Sorry, but using this function i am not getting the output. Displaying "Syntax error, unexpected 'function'" in eclipse. On the browser its displaying nothing

Comment: Activate PHP 5.3 support in eclipse and you should not see that message shown by eclipse. I also will add a PHP 5.2 compatible variant to the answer.

Comment: +1 for `simple string comparison` because of efficient formatting

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy:

First transform Date-Strings to Timestamps to get Integers.
Next and optional you can sort them.
At last walk another time through the Dates (now Integers) and collect the Range of Dates you want. 
While doing this you can re-transform the Integers to old Date Format.

Thats all.
Not more than 10 Lines of Code.

Ok, some want an example. Here it is:

```
// create a bunch of unsortable random dates-trash
$dates = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++)
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', rand(1000, time()));

// first transform it to timestamp integers
// if strtotime don't makes it, you have to transform your datesformat
// as one more pre-step
foreach($dates as $k => $v)
    $dates[$k] = strtotime($v);

// now and optional sort that (now finest) stuff
sort($dates);

// at last get the range of dates back
$datesInRange = array();
$dateStart = strtotime('1998-06-27');
$dateEnd = strtotime('2010-4-20');
foreach($dates as $date)
    if($date >= $dateStart AND $date <= $dateEnd)
        $datesInRange[] = date('Y-m-d', $date);

// have a look at the result
echo implode(',<br />', $datesInRange);
```

Comment: This answer would be significantly strong with some exemplar code, however simple.  Also: very common question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+by+date+php